# Compare difference between multiple numbers

Tags: javascript, math, logic, algebra

The problem is that I have array with 5 numbers:

300 295    250     105  100  95

The result needed: the most numbers that have least difference specified by threshold.
If you cant understand: in the example threshold is 5 and the winning set of numbers is 95,100,105 - because there are 3 numbers that are close to each other and the other set (295,300) is only 2.

I will try to come up with more clear explanation soon.

Comment: Not very clear... Are the numbers always sorted like in your example?

Comment: The question isn't well defined. Mr.Wizard's answer is good assuming you need a "running threshold" although I understood you to require a "fixed threshold". The difference would be in the set `{1,2,3,4}` with threshold `1`: I thought that the largest valid subset is `{1,2,3}` or `{2,3,4}` since around a median value they span only `1`, however a running threshold will acccept the entire set `{1,2,3,4}` since between *consecutive* values there is only a difference of `1`. Please clarify your requirements. I have a reasonably simple `O(nlogn)` solution if my understanding is correct.

Comment: well basically the threshold can be running if u insist
the final result what would i need - 1 number from the set and if the threshold is not big enough, it can be 1st 2nd or 3rd, no matter

but the best thing to have is the median number of the final set

Comment: real life example:  i have an array of songs with duration of 
[5:00, 4:50, 4:00, 3:20, 3:19, 3:15] - the idea is to select the proper version of the track, being 3:20 or 3:19

Comment: Ooh, now you lost me. Can you give another example, and explain how you got to the answer? At first I thought you were looking for continuous sequences where the members do not differ from their immediate neighbours by more than the threshold.

Comment: As a start, you can define a threshold *k* and a set *T* and ask: find the subset(s) *S* of *T* such that for each *a* and *b* in *S*, | *a* - *b* | <= *k*. Now over all such subsets *S* that satisfy this condition choose the one of largest cardinality.

Comment: mm yeah, but I probably should have stick with the javascript tag. because algorithm shall be implemented in code and i dont honestly know the best way to do it

Comment: basically, compare each element of array with every other element of array and find the elements that difference is less than threshold..... then of these elements select ones which form the biggest group of elements, see:  of [100,99,103,   5,3,1,9]  - the resulting group would be 5,3,1,9  because there are 4 elements rather than 3 in first group. and from them i will need [5,3,1] because they are closest, and from them i need 3 because its kind of median

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give Javascript code, but I propose:

- Sort the list
- Compute sequential differences
- round or clip any values below `threshold` to zero, and all others to one
- look for the longest continuous sequence of zeros (run-length encoding)

> ```
> {95, 100, 105, 250, 295, 300}
>
> --->  {5, 5, 145, 45, 5}
>
> --->  {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}
> ```

Comment: yes thank you very much, its great algorithm
but to compute differences is there any efficient algorithm for that?

Comment: @kolor I use a high level language (*Mathematica*) and methods do not translate well I believe.  If by chance javascript has array operators:  `RotateLeft(array) - array` and drop the last element.

Comment: Subtraction is usually the method used for computation of differences. And computers are quite good at addition and subtraction. What is wrong with a sort and a loop?

Comment: the question is how to get a second array from first one, with less computations. i can of course go through each element comparing with another one but that would be N^2, i would need something more like logN