# Closeness score to a target array of numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

It's hard to know what terms to search for on stackoverflow for this problem. Say you have a target array of numbers like `[100, 250, 400, 60]`

I want to be able to score the closeness other arrays have to this target based on a threshold / error bars of say 10. So for example, the array:
`[90, 240, 390, 50]` would get a high score (or positive match result) because of the error bars.

The order matters, so
`[60, 400, 250, 100]` would get zero score (or negative match result)

The arrays can be different sizes so
[33, 77, 300, **110, 260, 410, 60**, 99, 23] would get good score or positive match result.

A good way to think about the problem is to imagine these numbers are frequencies of musical notes like C,G,E,F and I'm trying to match a sequence of notes against a target.

Searching stackoverflow I'm not sure is this post will work, but it's close:
[Compare difference between multiple numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165361/compare-difference-between-multiple-numbers)

**Update 17th Jan 2015:**
I failed to mention a scenario that might affect current answers. If the array has noise between those target numbers, I still want to find a positive match. For example [33, 77, 300, **110**, **260**, 300, **410**, 40, **60**, 99, 23].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is **sequence similarity**.

You can read about them on [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment). Your case seems fit to local alignment category. There's some algorithm you can choose :

- [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm)
- [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

However, since these algorithms compare strings, you have to design your own scoring rule when inserting, deleting or comparing numbers.

Comment: Hi Kevin, if the array has noise between those target numbers, I still want to find a positive match. For example [33, 77, 300, 110, 260, 300, 410, 40 60, 99, 23]. Would this affect your answer? I've updated question.

Comment: @elprl : Those noise you mention is insertion alignment, there are examples about them in those wikipedia page. If you want to get positive match even when there are a lot of insertion, you can tweak the scoring system. For example, insert are given 0 score, but delete are given -100 score. Scoring the closeness of numbers itself can be computed using RMS method that user3386109 mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the RMS error, where RMS is the square **R**oot of the **M**ean **S**quared error. Let me illustrate by example.  Assume the target array is 
`[100, 250, 400, 60]` and the array to be scored is `[104, 240, 410, 55]`

First compute the difference values, i.e. the errors

```
 100    250    400    60
-104   -240   -410   -55
----   ----   ----   ---
  -4     10    -10     5
```

Then square the errors to get `16 100 100 25`. Compute the mean of the squared errors

```
(16 + 100 + 100 + 25) / 4 = 60.25
```

And finally, take the square root `sqrt(60.25) = 7.76`

When the arrays are different sizes, you can speed things up by only computing the RMS error if the first value is within a certain threshold, say +- 30. Using the example `[33, 77, 300, 110, 260, 410, 60, 99, 23]`, there would only be two alignments to check, because with the other alignments the first number is more than 30 away from 100

```
33  77 300 110 260 410  60  99  23
   100 250 400  60                  --> RMS score = 178
           100 250 400  60          --> RMS score = 8.7
```

Low score wins!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and examples. I'll give this a try also.

Comment: Hi, if the array has noise between those target numbers - I've updated question, would this render the RMS Deviation method useless?

Comment: @elprl I think the full answer is a combination of sequence similarity and RMS. The sequence similarity algorithms help you find the right alignment between the two sequences. The RMS calculation provides a score for numbers that don't match exactly. To apply RMS in the case where you have insertions/deletions (indels), you would need to assign an arbitrary error value to each indel, based on how important you think indels are. For example, a error of 10 could be used if indels are insignificant, or an error of 50 or 100 if indels are very significant.